# Poetry install grpcio fails with EnvCommandError

Tags: python, macos, macos-big-sur, python-poetry

I am using macOS BigSur 11.1, poetry 1.1.4 and python 3.8.6.
In my poetry project I try to run `poetry add grpcio`, but it results in `EnvCommandError` and an incredibly long output after running for several minutes.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5):

You can try to set `export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=true`
https://bleepcoder.com/fr/grpc/737099678/grpc-does-not-compile-on-mac-os-catalina-10-15-6-big-sur-11

It work for me.